# Naming convention of the generated form name (ASPXFORM)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My form-runat-server is inside of a masterpage, and I noticed the form id was generated "aspxform".

```
<form id="aspxform" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="page.aspx" method="post">
```

Has anyone had experience changing the ID of the form runat server element? Specifically,

- Will it break any native ASP.NET code? Client side validation, ajax, update-panels, etc.
- Have you experienced any third party code that relies on a specific id to find the form element?
- Do you have alternatives to finding the form-runat-server in javascript? (that is my real application)
- If you want to supply your own name, do you have to say clientmode="static" ? that is, do naming containers affect this form element since it is crucial to runat server functionality, and there can one be one -- it doesn't make sense to me that this element would fall in the naming container restrictions, but didn't know what experience you've had.

Comment: How long would it take for you to try it and find out?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry it's phrased like a homework question, that wasn't my intent. I guess I'm not asking about the 'how do you do it,' but rather for anyone with experience doing it. You're right, throwing it on a page would take some seconds, but the experience with how this works with other framework parts, various third party libraries, etc. is something that takes longer, and something the development community at large may be a good resource to answer with their experience. I realize the question doesn't do that justice.

Comment: If the id mattered, they wouldn't let you change it, or they would ignore your change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely specify your own id and it will be kept intact.

Comment: so there is no code in the bowels of .net that relies on this specific name? i guess deep down i'm a little afraid something will break.... ? You've had experience doing this?

Comment: @Matthew no, there isn't any code in the bowels of .net that relies on this being the form's id. As long as you only have 1 form with runat="server" on the page, you can call it with any id/name you want. I haven't come across any third party library that relies on this being the name either and if I ever do, I'd probably start working on getting rid of it as soon as I can, as this would be a clear indication of a very -excuse my French- shitty library. The project I'm working on uses a specific Id for the main form as we have several forms per page (again, only one with runat=server, though)